# Meteor parsing through a collection setInterval only works once

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I am trying to check something in a collection many times. On page load everything works great, but when the setInterval kicks in and try's to look over the data a second time it acts like the one peace of data is Null and can't find any info.

```
Template.something.helpers({
    repeatCheck: function repeatCheck() {
    setInterval(findTechs, 5000);
    console.log("repeatcheck");
  }
});

function findTechs() {
    _Queue.find({}).forEach(checkTime(this));
  };

  function checkTime(techInfo) {
  console.log(newTime);
  console.log(techInfo);
  console.log(techInfo.endTime < newTime);
  if (techInfo.endTime < newTime) {
    console.log("fun");
    if (_Queue.findOne({
        _id: techInfo._id
      })) {
      _Queue.remove({
        _id: techInfo._id
      })
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please be more specific and show the entire *relevant* code (for example, page load handler)

Comment: I am a little new to this so I am not sure what the load handler is. What I do know is that when I check a mongoDB collection once it works and the second time the page trys to do it though setInterval it fails. 

If you can explain what the handler is I will be happy to past it in so you can have a look.

Comment: Since you stated that "*on page load everything works great*", I was asking you to show how you handle page load events

Comment: this is the bit of code that I have used to call the function in js. I don't have anything in my code that says onload or anything like that. I have played around with that and I thought I would be best to try and get it working this way.

`<template name='techWorking'>
  <tr class="techWorking" bgcolor="{{color}}">
    <td>{{name}} {{repeatCheck}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{>options}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{totaltickets}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{dispatched}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{livestamp timesincelast}}</td>
    <td class="center">
  </tr>
</template>`

Comment: So to touch on this again. I have a queue of people that are all in one collection, I would like to check that collection every X amount of time and using some of the elements inside each one determine if they should be in or out of another collection. the other collection is a queue of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your JS.

```
function findTechs() {
  _Queue.find({}).forEach(checkTime(this));
};
```

This will call `checkTime` once with the current context as an argument. `this` probably refers to the `window` object here. In JavaScript a function call is made when there are brackets behind a variable containing a function. So `checkTime(this)` calls `checkTime` and then returns what a call to `checkTime` will return. Then `cursor.forEach` is called with that value (which is `undefined`). So the documents inside the cursor are iterated over with `undefined`, which does nothing.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
_Queue.find({}).forEach(checkTime);
```

Here the actual function behind the `checkTime` variable is passed  to the `cursor.forEach` call.

You might want to read up on JavaScript callbacks.

Comment: first I have to say thank you and I will for sure read about callbacks and many other things when dealing with code. Other than messing with the almost js that is in googlesheets, this is my only time messing with the stuff. 

I want to say thank you again this seems to be working great. No errors in the console witch is a first in a few days. THANK YOU.